# GeoNames cities list missing many cities that appear on website

Tags: geonames

I am trying to set up a table with cities. 
I have downloaded the cities500, cities1000, cities5000 lists, but strangely enough they are missing rather big and popular cities/towns that ARE present on GeoNames website.

A couple of examples for these :

1. Ronda, Spain - https://www.geonames.org/2511730/ronda.html
2. Ribe, Denmark - https://www.geonames.org/2614813/ribe.html

Is there something I'm missing here? How come even though GeoNames does seem to contain those cities, the lists on the download server don't have them?

**UPDATE :**

I was using a bad CSV editor tool, both Ronda and Ribe do exist in the dump file.

Comment: I checked cities5000 and I see Ronda there, here is some info from file: `2511730 Ronda Ronda RRA,Ronda,Ронда 36.74231 -5.16709 P PPLA3 ES`.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I was using a bad CSV editor tool (Tablecruncher). I opened this up with Sublime, and both Ronda and Ribe now appear.
On the other hand, places like Hallstatt are abscent from there, even though I can find them on the Geonames website : 'https://www.geonames.org/2776943/hallstatt.html'

Comment: Ah, I probably know why.. the population of Hallstatt according to GeoNames is below 500, while in fact it's 779 according to Wiki. 
Is there a way to get the list of towns with population less than 500 people? And if I edit the population count for Hallstatt for example, how soon until the dump file updated ?